# Tensor 'embedding_input' has invalid shape '[None, None]'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, tensorflow-lite

I am trying to create a tensorflow lite text multi-class classification model. I mostly copied the code from here: https://colab.research.google.com/github/tensorflow/docs/blob/master/site/en/tutorials/keras/basic_text_classification.ipynb

Everything seems to work fine in tensorflow, but when I try to convert the save h5 model to **Tensorflow Lite** I get this error:

`ValueError: None is only supported in the 1st dimension. Tensor 'embedding_input' has invalid shape '[None, None]'.`

This is what my code looks like:

```
vocab_size = 15000 # of words in dictionary

model = keras.Sequential()
model.add(keras.layers.Embedding(vocab_size, 16))
model.add(keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling1D())
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(16, activation=tf.nn.relu))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(7, activation=tf.nn.sigmoid))

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

history = model.fit(...)
keras.models.save_model(model, graphFile)

converter = tf.contrib.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model_file(graphFile)
tflite_model = converter.convert()
open("converted.tflite", "wb").write(tflite_model)
```

I'm guessing the issue is with the Embedding layer? What can I do to fix it?

Comment: Where do you define the tensor 'embedding_input' that you refer to?

Comment: I don't declare that anywhere...I assume it comes from `model.add(keras.layers.Embedding(vocab_size, 16))`

Comment: Okay. And what does vocab_size hold?

Comment: # of words in dictionary, added to post

Answer (score 1):

The convert requires to know the shape of input tensor. Only the 1st dimension (batch) can be unknown (`None`). In some case, Keras doesn't annotate the known tensor shape. You can specify the input shape by passing the `input_shapes` optional argument:

```
converter = tf.contrib.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model_file(
    graphFile,
    input_shapes={'embedding_input': [1, vocab_size]}
)
```

See also a similar issue: [Tensorflow - h5 model to tflite conversion error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54211413/tensorflow-h5-model-to-tflite-conversion-error)

Comment: input_shapes is not available in tensorflow 2.0